# Switch Between views in FrameLayout

Tags: android, surfaceview, dialog, android-framelayout

How do you switch between views in a FrameLayout? For example, I have one SurfaceView in my FrameLayout and I want it to display a DialogBox when the game is over to receive user text input. I'm assuming that DialogBox will be stored as another view in the FrameLayout, but how do I actually display it? I'll need to call it from my SurfaceView, because when something happens in the SurfaceView, that DialogBox needs to be displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`bringChildToFront(view)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#bringChildToFront%28android.view.View%29) to show any child view above other child views.

Comment: Can that be called from a view itself? Also, would a Dialog be considered a view?

Comment: Yes `getParent().bringChildToFront(view)`. No, dialogs do not implement View. AFAIK, you can start Dialog from any context - no for all this.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting that line of code to work. I have a LinearLayout called l1 that has an edittext in it, a framelayout that contains the linear layout AND my gameboard. When something happens in the gameboard, I want to display the LinearLayout(which is called l1). It needs to be called from inside the gameboard (which is a SurfaceView) but it isn't working. Do I have to pass the name of l1 to it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

See this page for help with [Creating Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)